# switch custom using laravel , ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have the following datatable :

[image]

In My controller I have this function which gets data :

```
function getdata(Request $request)
    {
        if(request()->ajax())
        {
            return datatables()->of(Casting::latest()->get())
                    ->addColumn('action', function($data){
                        $button = '<table><tr><td>';
                        $button .= '<button type="button"     name="edit" id="'.$data->id.'" class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm">Modifier</button>';
                        $button .= '</td><td>';
                        $button .= '<div class="custom-switch custom-switch-secondary-inverse mb-2 custom-switch-small">
                                                <input class="custom-switch-input" name="switchS4" id="switchS4" type="checkbox">
                                                <label class="custom-switch-btn" for="switchS4"></label>
                                            </div>';

                        $button .= '</td></tr></table>';
                  return $button;
                    })
                    ->rawColumns(['action'])
                    ->make(true);
        }
       return view('Casting.castingss');

    }
```

And the following code is my script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

 $('#datatableRows').DataTable({
  processing: true,
  serverSide: true,
  ajax:{
   url: "{{ route('castingss.getdata') }}",
  },
  columns:[
  
   {
    data: 'casting_photo',
    name: 'casting_photo',
    render: function(data, type, full, meta){
              return "<img src={{ URL::to('/') }}/castingimages/" + data +  " class='list-thumbnail responsive border-0 card-img-left' />";
    },
    orderable: false
   },
   {data:'casting_name',
    name: 'casting_name',
    render:function(data,type,full,meta){
      return "<a href='profile'>" + data + "</a>";
    }
   },
    {
    data: 'casting_cin',
    name: 'casting_cin'
   },
    {
    data: 'casting_phone',
    name: 'casting_phone'
   },
   
   {
    data: 'action',
    name: 'action',
    orderable: false
   }
  ]
 });
});
</script>
```

The problem is that in my database table I have the status column equal to 1 and when I display data in m datatable the switch custom is always deactivated.

**EDIT**

```
    function getdata(Request $request)
{
    if(request()->ajax())
    {
        return datatables()->of(Casting::latest()->get())
            ->addColumn('action', function($data){
                $button = '<table><tr><td>';
                $button .= '<button type="button" name="edit" id="'.$data->id.'" class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm">Modifier</button>';
                $button .= '</td><td>';
                $button .= '<div class="custom-switch custom-switch-secondary-inverse mb-2 custom-switch-small">';
                $button .= '<input class="custom-switch-input" name="switchS4" id="switchS4" data-id = "'.$data->id.'" type="checkbox"';
                if ($data->status == 1) {
                    $button .= 'checked';
                }
                $button .= '><label class="custom-switch-btn" for="switchS4"></label></div>';
                $button .= '</td></tr></table>';
                return $button;
        })
        ->rawColumns(['action'])
        ->make(true);
    }
    return view('Casting.castingss');
}
```

and I add this script just for testing if it works :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('switchS4').change(function () {
      alert('I am here');
        /**/
    });
});
</script>
```

But I can just switch the first row of the datable ana the alert doesn't show up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to have the custom switch on when a table record's status column is 1. You are not checking for this where you create the HTML for the custom switch.

Change your `getdata` function as follows :-

```
function getdata(Request $request)
{
    if(request()->ajax())
    {
        return datatables()->of(Casting::latest()->get())
            ->addColumn('action', function($data){
                $button = '<table><tr><td>';
                $button .= '<button type="button" name="edit" id="'.$data->id.'" class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm">Modifier</button>';
                $button .= '</td><td>';
                $button .= '<div class="custom-switch custom-switch-secondary-inverse mb-2 custom-switch-small">';
                $button .= '<input class="custom-switch-input" name="switchS4" id="switchS4" type="checkbox"';
                if ($data->status == 1) {
                    $button .= 'checked';
                }
                $button .= '><label class="custom-switch-btn" for="switchS4"></label></div>';
                $button .= '</td></tr></table>';
                return $button;
        })
        ->rawColumns(['action'])
        ->make(true);
    }
    return view('Casting.castingss');
}
```

Comment: Happy to help. Good luck on your coding journey! :)

Comment: If it is possible I have just a question, Now I want to update the status in the database, I should add an id like id="'.$data->id.'" to my custom switch ??

Comment: That's how I would do it. Add the id to the custom switch, and make a JS function that does an AJAX call with the id and the value to change status to.

Comment: Okey I will try

Comment: please check my EDIT if it is possible

Comment: You are missing the # before `switchS4`. `$('#switchS4').change(function() {`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233301/discussion-between-will-walsh-and-ha-jar).